# subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector (C)

Tags: arrays, c

I’m new to programing in C and have run into a problem trying to add a value to an array.
When trying to ad the value the following error is thrown: “subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector”.

If someone could help me out, I would be thankful 
Here is my code:

The array is declared in the main function as followed:

```
int main(void) {
    entity_e *entity = spawnEntity(1, 2, 140, 30, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1);
    int xyGrid[10][5];

    while(1) {
        updateEntity(entity, xyGrid, -1, 1);
    }
}
```

The update Entity function calls on the array, and tries to pass a value to it:

```
void updateEntity(entity_e *entity, int *xyGrid, int32_t kx, int32_t ky) {
    for(int i=0; i<5; i ++) {
        gotoxy(entity[i].x_position, entity[i].y_position);
        printf("%s", "     ");
        xyGrid[entity[i].x_position][entity[i].y_position] = 0;     #Error accrues here.
    }
}
```

The values for (entity[i].x_position) and (entity[i].x_position) are generated in the spawnEntity function:

```
entity_e* spawnEntity(int8_t indexMin, int8_t indexMax, int8_t xPosition, int8_t yPosition]) {

    static entity_e spawn[3];

    for(int i=indexMin; i<indexMax; i++) {
        spawn[i].x_position = xPosition;
        spawn[i].y_position = yPosition;
        }
    return spawn;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: updateEntity says `int *xyGrid` but that is not the type of xyGrid in `main`.

Comment: C does not have vectors as a language feature.  Are you sure you're not compiling with a C++ compiler?

Comment: `spawnEntity` takes 4 parameters but you pass 10. How is that supposed to work? What does your compiler say about that?

Answer (score 2):

This ...

> ```
>     int xyGrid[10][5];
> ```

... in `main` declares `xyGrid` as an array of 10 arrays of 5 `int`s.  In most contexts, such an array value is automatically converted upon evaluation to a pointer to the first array element.  In this case, the first array element has type "array of 5 `int`", so the resulting pointer is a pointer to an array (of 5 `int`).  That can be spelled `int (*)[5]`, and it is not at all the same thing as `int *`.

When you call ...

> ```
>         updateEntity(entity, xyGrid, -1, 1);
> ```

... you are passing an `int (*)[5]` argument where the function expects to receive an `int *`.  This produces undefined behavior, and if your compiler is not warning you about that then you should either turn up the warning level until it does, or get a better compiler.  (And if the compiler *is* warning, then why are you not paying attention to that?)

The error you ask about is related to that mismatch, but does not arise directly from it.  The problem is that in function `updateEntity()`, the compiler interprets parameter `xyGrid` according to the type declared for it *in that function*, which is `int *`.  From that perspective, consider the erroneous expression:

> ```
> xyGrid[entity[i].x_position][entity[i].y_position]
> ```

The indexing operator associates from right to left, so that's equivalent to

```
(xyGrid[entity[i].x_position])[entity[i].y_position]
```

Now, what's the type of sub-expression `xyGrid[entity[i].x_position]`?  `xyGrid` is an `int *` and `entity[i].x_position` is presumably an integer, so that's a valid expression whose type is `xyGrid`'s pointed-to type, `int`.

So now we have

```
(some integer value)[entity[i].y_position]
```

Both operands of *that* indexing expression are integers, which is not valid.  **This is the nature of the error.**

The most direct solution would be to correct the signature of `updateEntity()` to match both its implementation and its usage:

```
void updateEntity(entity_e *entity, int (*xyGrid)[5], int32_t kx, int32_t ky) {
```

You could also spell that

```
void updateEntity(entity_e *entity, int xyGrid[][5], int32_t kx, int32_t ky) {
```

or even

```
void updateEntity(entity_e *entity, int xyGrid[10][5], int32_t kx, int32_t ky) {
```

.  All of those mean exactly the same thing in that particular context.